# Ember.js - Integration Testing with Ember-CLI

Tags: ember.js, integration-testing, ember-cli

I am following a [Dockyard Tutorial](http://reefpoints.dockyard.com/2014/05/08/building-an-ember-app-with-rails-part-2.html) on using ember-cli with rails. This particular section is on basic integration testing. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be registering properly (at least I don't think so). The test should fail and say something along the lines of "Expected: 'Welcome to Boston Ember'"; rather, it says "should pass jshint" which it is and is therefore passing. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

**tests/integration/landing-page-test.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import startApp from 'bostonember/tests/helpers/start-app';

var App;

module('Integration - Landing Page', {
  setup: function() {
    App = startApp();
  },
  teardown: function() {
    Ember.run(App, 'destroy');
  }
});

test('Should welcome me to Boston Ember', function() {
  visit('/').then(function() {
    equal(find('h2#title').text(), 'Welcome bloopde bloopasa to Boston Ember');
  });
});
```

**tests/helpers/start-app.js**

```
/* global require */

var Application = require('bostonember/app')['default'];
var Router = require('bostonember/router')['default'];
import Ember from 'ember';

export default function startApp(attrs) {
  var App;

  var attributes = Ember.merge({
    // useful Test defaults
    rootElement: '#ember-testing',
    LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION:false,
    LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS: false
  }, attrs); // but you can override;

  Router.reopen({
    location: 'none'
  });

  Ember.run(function(){
    App = Application.create(attributes);
    App.setupForTesting();
    App.injectTestHelpers();
  });

  App.reset(); // this shouldn't be needed, i want to be able to "start an app at a specific URL"

  return App;
}
```

Will provide additional info upon request. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must have just been a hiccup? 
Solution was to recreate the file, same code, but works now.